# Is there a general rule/formula for the length of an ice age?

Tags: science-based, climate, earth-like

Right now in our worldbuilding project, my friends and I are working on the history of the world with respect to evolution and tectonics. Recently (322 mya) I was pretty sure an ice age would be triggered, because of the photosynthesizers proliferating uncompeted across the shores right after the invasion of land.

As a clarification, **I'm just looking for guidelines ─ not a precise formula.**

But the question is, how long would the glacial period last? For some astronomical and terrestrial information:

- The star is 1.259 solar masses.
- The planet is 1.261 Earth masses.
- The planet has 41.47 degrees of axial tilt.
- The planet orbits at 1.602 AU from the star on average. (The perihelion is 1.575 AU, and the aphelion is 1.629 AU).
- I don't have exact data for the atmospheric composition at all times; I can make some if needed, but would rather not.

Comment: Downvotes without comment don't lead to improved questions, folks.

Comment: Little known fact: users who get downvoted don't automatically become aware of the reasons that led their question to receive the downvotes. One can't really fix a problem if all they're told is "there's a problem".

Comment: The extreme tilt means there will be some pretty extreme weather (hot *and* cold).

Comment: @RonJohn I know; do you think that would affect the ice age?

Comment: I didn't downvote it, but in this case it seems rather obvious - the answer is hard "no". All the planets are different, there are myriads of factors affecting "ice age". There can't possibly be any formula - we have a single planet with very specific parameters and extrapolating "data" we have to general formula would be absolutely impossible. Edit: you know what, now that I wrote it, I downvoted it.

Comment: @nearsighted maybe. The planet is far enough away that it might be outside the Goldilocks Zone, and thus be *permanently* frozen.

Comment: @nearsighted Mars is only 1.5AU from the Sun.  Your star is a little larger, so *maybe* brighter.  Or maybe not…

Comment: @D'Monlord Not a precise formula, just guidelines. I'll edit the question to clarify.

Comment: @RonJohn Nah, you can put the data into Artifexian's *Worldsmith* spreadsheet and see that it's comfortably within the habitable zone.

Comment: @nearsighted And it still makes no sense. Ice age is a product of climate, climate is one of the hardest things to compute. After centuries of observation meteorologists still need supercomputers to determine if there will be rain 3 days from now. No, there are no guidelines for infinitely complex once-in-a thousands of years event on a worlds of arbitrary mass and axial tilt. Hundreds of years - believable, thousands - too, millions - easy. Your planet can be frozen all the time for all the info you gave about it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have no idea about any general formula, so all I can offer is what geology tells us. In general, I am skeptical about our ability to actually *calculate* anything much with respect to climate beyond the immediate future, and even that with massive assumptions; climatology is still primarily an observational science.

- The [Sturtian glaciation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturtian_glaciation) lasted for about 57 million years and ended about 660 million years ago.
- The [Marinoan = Varanger glaciation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snowball_Earth) lasted for about 28 million years, and may have covered *the entire world* in ice. It ended some 630 million years ago. It is the strange geological period commonly known as "Snowball Earth".
- The [Quaternary glaciation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternary_glaciation) began some 2.6 million years ago and is still going strong. Note that this is most usually subsumed into a much larger [Late Cenozoic ice age](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Late_Cenozoic_Ice_Age) which began some 34 million years ago.

  Yes, we are living in an ice age. Since we are living in it, we know it better than others which came before. It consists of a series of alternating [glacial periods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glacial_period) when polar ice sheets grow and mountains glaciers advance, and [interglacial periods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interglacial) when polar ice sheets shrink and mountain glaciers retreat. (If it is not obvious, at present we are in an interglacial, which began about 11,700 years ago.)

  In continental Europe, the last three glacial periods are called [Mindel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mindel_glaciation) (about 100,000 years, ended about 330,000 years ago), [Riss](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riss_glaciation) (about 170,000 years, ended about 130,000 years ago), and [Würm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/W%C3%BCrm_glaciation) (about 100,000 years, ended about 11,700 years ago). In other places other names are used, and the glacial periods may not be completely synchronized with what is observed in continental Europe.

To summarize:

- Most usually (in geologic time) there is no permanent ice anywhere on Earth and the sea level is about 100 meters (300 feet) above what we see now.
- The time when *there is* permanent ice on Earth, and as a consequence the sea level is low, is called an [ice age](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ice_age). Such an ice age lasts for many millions of years.
- During an ice age, there are times, called interglacials, when permanent ice is confined to polar ice sheets and mountain glaciers, and other times, called glacials, when polar ice sheets expand and mountain glaciers advance creating mini-ice-sheets of their own.
- Each of the last three glacials lasted for about 100,000 years, and they were separated by much shorter interglacials lasting 10,000 to 20,000 years.

Comment: If the Sturtian glaciation ended 660Mya, and the Marinoan glaciation lasted 28My, finishing 630Mya, then there was only 2 million years between those events.  Sounds more like one giant glaciation with a brief interregnum.

Comment: @RonJohn: That's why they are both included in the aptly named [Cryogenian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryogenian) period. (In geology, a "period" is a second-level subdivision of geological time; e.g., the Jurassic is a period. We are living in the Quaternary period of the Cenozoic era.)

Answer (score 2):

The answer you're looking for would require supercomputer level calculations. The major factors would be:

- Atmospheric composition
- Distance to the star
- Recent brightness of the star (our sun has been getting brighter)
- Axial tilt
- Eccentricity of the orbit
- Albedo of the surface (vegetation, etc)
- Cloud cover

For instance, the Cryogenien period was, to the best of our knowledge, started by the breakup of a supercontinent and ended by the eruption of underwater supervolcanoes.

This means that nobody is going to run the numbers and call you on whatever you want to make up.